# Python 3.4 not showing pip as available module

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I have Python 2.7.6 and Python 3.4.3. I am trying to use websocket in my python application but it seems it won't install for python 2.7.6 so I am using python 3. Supposedly pip comes with python 3.4 but I am unsure about how to use it.

`pip3` doesn't return anything

`python3 -m pip` returns no module named pip

What could be the issue here. How do I access my pip for python3 and so I can install websockets?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1

Comment: Have you installed `pip3` using `sudo apt-install python3-pip`?

Comment: When you say it won't install, can you specify the error?

Comment: You can alternatively also use: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/